# What's the translation of “tracker" as in "Covid-19 vaccination tracker" in French?

Tags: traduction

I am trying to translate from English to French:

> Covid-19 vaccination tracker

What's the translation of “tracker"?

---

My research:

1. The word "traqueur" didn't seem to mean tracker according to https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/traqueur and https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/traqueur/79270
2. Google Translate and Reverso did not help.

Comment: What is a tracker here ? A tool? A website? a process? a person ?

Comment: @XouDo computer program or website. Note that sometimes it can be a device as in wearable fitness tracker.

Answer (score 11):

Tracker is sometimes [used as is](https://covidtracker.fr/vaccintracker/) in French, and often pronounced like *traqueur*.

If you want something more French, ***suivi*** would be close:

> Logiciel de suivi des vaccinations contre le covid-19.

or

> Site de suivi des vaccinations...

The government site about it is precisely using *[Suivi de la vaccination](https://dashboard.covid19.data.gouv.fr/vue-d-ensemble?location=FRA)* (3rd tab).

***Suivi*** is more like "tracking" but unfortunately, *suiveur* (closer to "tracker") wouldn't work well here.

Note that French has a verb semantically closer to the verb "to track", ***pister*** but only used when the location of something is tracked. *Pister* means *suivre à la trace* (from *piste* = track).

*Pister les vaccinations* wouldn't make much sense but *pister les déplacements d'un super-contaminateur* (track a super-spreader) or *pister un animal* (track an animal) would. There is also *dépister* that means find the evidence of the presence of something (to screen): *Dépister le covid-19*.

In a broader way, the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track) lists the following meanings for the verb "to track":

> 1 a: to follow the tracks or traces of : TRAIL
>    b: to search for by following evidence until found *track down the source*
> 2 a: to follow by vestiges : TRACE
>    b: to observe or plot the moving path of (something, such as a spacecraft or missile) often instrumentally
> 3 a: to carry (mud or other material) on the feet and deposit
> *tracking mud into the kitchen*
>    b: to make tracks upon
> 4: to keep track of (something, such as a trend) : FOLLOW
> 5: to travel over : TRAVERSE *track a desert*

Here are French verbs close to each acceptation:

1 *pister, suivre à la trace*, *prendre en filature*
2 *suivre*, (*tracer*)
3 *laisser des traces (de son passage)*
4 *suivre*
5 *traverser*

None of them really match *faire l'état des lieux* which, being more static, doesn't convey well the evolving/moving meaning of track.

Finally, both Google translate and DeepL (the best online translation service so far) currently translate "Covid-19 vaccination tracker" to *Suivi de la vaccination Covid-19* ([DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/Covid-19%20vaccination%20tracker)) ([Google](https://translate.google.com/?sl=co&tl=fr&text=Covid-19%20vaccination%20tracker%0A&op=translate)). [Reverso](https://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=anglais-francais) gives *Outil de suivi de la vaccination contre la Covid-19* which is a little verbose but not bad anyway as it properly carry the meaning of tool while *suivi* is not the tool but what the tool achieves.

Comment: Same opinion here. To track, here, means to follow the development, so it can be translated into « suivre ». However be aware that this will not always be the case. For example, to track his last location CANNOT be translated into « suivre sa dernière position ». This is because to track is about to find out something in a more general sense than simply following as in being after something. Track his last location would be something like « déterminer sa dernière position ».

Comment: Voir aussi [ici](https://solidarites-sante.gouv.fr/grands-dossiers/vaccin-covid-19/je-suis-un-particulier/article/foire-aux-questions-le-suivi-du-deploiement-de-la-vaccination).

Comment: @Exocytosis Your statement on whether tracking one's last position can be translated to _suivre_ or not is unsubstantiated (ask the question?). In any case that wouldn't logically imply that the substantive _suivi_ couldn't be perfectly adequate for the noun _tracker_ in the context of the question. It is up for debate and cannot be brushed off in a comment.

Comment: Your link does not provide any historical background on the evolution of the vaccination. It is not any more dynamic than an état des lieux. More generally, suivi does not provide history.

Comment: @Winston *Suivi* is dynamic in the sense it is regularily updated while *état des lieux* is static, and done once. Of course you can do a new *état des lieux* but this term doesn't carry the monitoring aspect of suivi.

Comment: Ma réflexion m'amène à penser que ça prend toujours deux termes pour _track_ + -er et que c'est tout l'univers référentiel du _track_ qui est mal adapté à l'expression française en science dans ce contexte-là. Sur STAT ils ont un _vaccine tracker_ qui se veut une liste avec des détails sur l'avancement de chacun des vaccins etc. Est-ce un suivi de l'un ou un état des lieux de l'autre ? Dans un document désigné comme un « tableau de bord » je trouve « situation » dans le titre et il y a divers indicateurs dont un « vaccins administrés » qui réfère à des données du jour et cumulatives.

Comment: Les morceaux du _tracker_ sont comme pour ainsi dire saupoudrés à deux trois endroits dans le document.

Answer (score 6):

Although I agree with jilliagre's answer, I would like to point out that there is a more appropriate phrase in French for this kind of tracking. This is « état des lieux », as in « état des lieux des vaccinations en France ». The phrase « état des lieux » means « current state of affairs ». This is not a translation of « tracker » because there is not an exact one.

Also please read my comment under jilliagre's answer regarding the use of suivre or suivi as a translation of track. Track is not a perfect synonym of follow.

Below is an example of an official (French ministry of health) document:

Etat des lieux de la couverture vaccinale en France

https://solidarites-sante.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/2-etat_des_lieux_vaccination-2.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The two answers you have are very good, but which one is appropriate depends on the kind of data you want to show.

*Suivi* is dynamic - you show how something changed in time. *Suivi des vaccinations* means "How many shots were done in time".

*Etat des lieux* is static: it is a number. *Etat des lieux de la couverture vaccinale* shows where we are today, without information on how we came there (if you look at the linked PDF it shows just that)

Comment: No. Suivi does not imply historical data. It is a mere report of a present state. There is no such difference between suivi and état des lieux.

Comment: @Winston: According to Larousse:  *État des lieux: écrit constatant l'état dans lequel se trouve un appartement à l'entrée et à la sortie d'un locataire, signé par le bailleur et le locataire et annexé au contrat de location* → a static state | *Suivi: Ensemble d'opérations consistant à suivre et à contrôler un processus pour parvenir dans les meilleures conditions au résultat recherché : Le suivi d'une affaire, d'un produit.
Contrôle permanent sur une période étendue d'une expérience, d'un traitement, etc. : Le suivi médical des élèves* → data in time.

Comment: Your dictionary is clearly limited. État des lieux is not just about rentals. cf. « état des lieux du sexisme en France », etc.

Comment: @Winston This is not my dictionary. This is le Larousse. *Etat des lieux*, as an expression, was extended to the topics you mentioned. Another dictionary (Le Robert - not mine either) gives "Qui se fait d'une manière continue" for suivi. If you are French or went to school in France, these dictionaries are immediately recognized as prime references.